# Android cookies using phonegap

Tags: android, cookies, cordova

I have developed a phonegap application that has a user login page with a text box for username/password, a check box for "remember my info", and a submit button.

Pretty standard.

When I open it in Firefox, the cookie works fine and my login data is remembered when the box is checked.

However, when using the android emulator, my cookie is not saved, despite "navigator.cookieEnabled" returning true when printed on the emulator for debugging.

I can post the relevant code if needed but my question is more general:

How can you store cookies in android programming using the web based languages that PhoneGap supports?  Is it similar to normal web page javascript cookies?  Is there a method other than "navigator.cookieEnabled" that will return whether or not cookies are enabled for the android device?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For mobile application development HTML5 has new feature for Local Store and Session Store.
Same like cookies and session in web development

Try with ***localStorage*** option. I worked this way only.

For storing values in local storage i.e stored in browser permanently

```
window.localStorage.setItem("key", "Value");
```

For getting values in local storage

```
window.localStorage.getItem("Key")
```

For manually remove values for local storage

```
window.localStorage.removeItem("Key")
```

If you want to **manage session** you need to use ***sessionStorage*** option.

For storing values in session storage i.e values destroyed once mobile apps closed

```
window.sessionStorage.setItem("key", "Value");
```

For getting values in session storage

```
window.sessionStorage.getItem("Key")
```

For manually remove values for session storage

```
window.sessionStorage.removeItem("Key")
```

Comment: Does localStorage sessionStorage work on Windows Phone? I tried localStorage on my desktop IE in a local file and IE told me that it does not support localStorage for local files. As we know, PhoneGap/Cordova apps are essentially a bunch of files accessed locally from a folder, thus I'm curious if IE on Windows Phone also has the restriction regarding localStorage and local files.